# Determining the location number of a graph $G$

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization

Consider the following graph, $G$. I want to determine the location number of $G$.
[image: G]

From the source I am using to learn graph theory, an ordered set $S=\{w_1, w_2, ..., w_k\}$  of vertices in a connected graph $G$ such that for every two vertices $u$ and $v$ of $G$, there is some vertex $w_i \in S$ whose distance to $u$ is different from its distance to $v$ is a *locating set*. In addition, the minimum number of vertices in a locating set is the *location number* of $G$.

My approach has been to test various possibilities of $S$ and see whether or not $S$ coveres the whole of $G$. For example, if I select two vertices of $G$ at random, I can define a collection or ordered pairs $(x, y)$ for every other vertex in $G$ consisting of the distance from a said vertex to both of the vertices in $S$. If any number of ordered pairs are the same, then $S$ is not a locating set. Other than this, I am not sure of any good approached for a problem of this sort, as this has not been very successful. All I have proven is that the location number is greater than 1.

That being said, any redirection to a text or reading to help with my understanding would be appreciated!

Comment: A better approach is to choose candidate sets $S$ with intent, rather than at random. For example, say you notice that the leftmost vertex distinguishes the different "columns" in the diagram from each other, but cannot tell the three vertices in a column apart. Then you might try to pick a second vertex that can reliably tell apart the three vertices in a column.

Comment: This is a very helpful addition to the approach, thank you! I also realized that I have not been considering the ordered pairs (x, y, ..., z), depending on the cardinality of S, as actually ordered. I need to keep consistent which vertex in S relates to which element in each ordered pair. Otherwise, I'll run into incorrect counterexamples. I believe this is sufficient to determine a locating number. Thank you!

Comment: Edit: Let S be the set containing the left-most vertex and the middle-most vertex in the bottom column. Constructing ordered pairs as stated in the question gives proof that the locating number for $G$ is 2. Very nice

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this *set covering* problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $N$ be the node set, let $P=\{u\in N, v\in N: u < v\}$ be the set of node pairs, and let $d_{uv}$ be the shortest path distance from $u$ to $v$.  For $(u,v)\in P$, let $N_{uv}=\{i\in N: d_{iu} \not= d_{iv}\}$.  For $i\in N$, let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether $i\in S$.  The problem is to minimize $$|S|=\sum_{i\in N} x_i$$ subject to linear constraints
$$\sum_{i\in N_{uv}} x_i \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $(u,v)\in P$}.$$
These constraints force at least one $i\in S \cap N_{uv}$ for each node pair $(u,v)$.

---

For your sample graph, if you number the nodes from left to right and top to bottom so that the top left node is $2$ and the bottom left node is $4$, we have $N_{2,4}=\{2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,16\}$, which is the set of nodes that do not appear in the middle row.  The graph has $17$ nodes, so $|P|=\binom{17}{2}=136$, and there are $136$ constraints.  For example, the constraint for $(u,v)=(2,4)$ is
$$x_2+x_4+x_5+x_7+x_8+x_{10}+x_{11}+x_{13}+x_{14}+x_{16} \ge 1.$$  The minimum $|S|$ turns out to be $2$, and one optimal solution is $x_1=x_{10}=1$, with all other $x_i=0$.  There are $20$ such optimal solutions, each consisting of either node $1$ or node $17$, together with any node from the top or bottom row.